# Express API not responding when deployed on AWS LightSail

Tags: node.js, linux, express

I am working on an API based service that was made and tested locally first and then deployed on AWS LightSail Ubuntu 20.04 . For whatever reason the server is not responding, as hitting any routes is neither logging nor sending a response back. FYI I tried other clients like the chrome console, postman etc. This is a simplified version of the code that was tested as well.

```
    const express = require("express");
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const cors = require('cors');

    const app = express();

    app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

    app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
      res.send({
       "msg":"worked"
      });
        console.log("hit hit hit");
    });

   app.listen(3000,()=>{
       console.log("server started at port 3000");
   })
```

Comment: Are you accessing the server on the correct port (3000) as well? There is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Yes I am accessing the same port. FYI I know the server is working as I can access a static webpage that it is serving at port 8080. The problem is with my express API.